# What's the difference between a view and a query?

Tags: sql

In SSMS and MySQLWorkbench a view is the SQL that generates a result set. In Access those are called queries. Is a view the same as a query?

Comment: In SSMS and MySQLWorkbench a view is the SQL that generates a "cursor" - No, it's not. A view is a virtual table that consists of columns from one or more tables.

Comment: "A cursor is a table" - no it is not.

Comment: A table is a persisted data structure containing one or more columns and zero or more rows of data. A cursor is a logical structure used for accessing query data.  It is not a table, it is not a view.

Answer (score 0):

A view is essentially a stored/predefined query.  Depending on the database in question, views may additionally have indexes defined against them, have referential integrity defined on them, and/or be materialized (pre-queried and persisted to disk).